# How to fix 401 error when the credentials work on one end but not the other

Tags: angular, spring, spring-security

When I try to log in the angular portion of my app I get a 401 error but the credentials work in the spring portion. No matter what I try I can't seem to fix it. I was following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QV7ke4a7Lvc&t=11s)

Header

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 401 
Remote Address: [::1]:8080
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: access_token, authorization, content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Max-Age: 4200
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Date: Sat, 18 Sep 2021 16:40:45 GMT
Expires: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Pragma: no-cache
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Realm"
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Realm"
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

Spring Security config This portion works well enough to allow me to sign into the spring server.

```
    @Configuration
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Autowired
    private CorsConfiguration myCorsFilter;

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception
    {
        // Allow Login API to be accessed without authentication
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/login").antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**"); // Request type options should be allowed.
    }

//CORS


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
     /*   http.cors().and().csrf().
                disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .fullyAuthenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();*/

        http.addFilterBefore(myCorsFilter, ChannelProcessingFilter.class);


        http.cors();
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").fullyAuthenticated().and()
                .httpBasic();
    }



    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("dave")
                .password("{noop}dave").roles("USER");


    }
}
```

CorsFilter

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class CorsConfiguration implements Filter {

    /**
     * CORS filter for http-request and response
     */
    public void CORSFilter() {
    }

    /**
     * Do Filter on every http-request.
     */

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "4200");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "access_token, authorization, content-type");

        if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Destroy method
     */
    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

    /**
     * Initialize CORS filter
     */
    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you have a custom cors filter when there is already one in spring security? Also learn to enable spring security debugging logs as these will tell you exactly why you are getting a 401. Learn to debug your application before asking on stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing two spaces after my basics in my front end

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders({Authorization: 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ':' + password) });
    return this.http.get("http://localhost:8080",{headers,responseType: 'text' as 'json'})
  }

  getUsers() {
    let username='dave'
    let password='dave'
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({Authorization: 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ':' + password) });
    return this.http.get("http://localhost:8080/getUsers",{headers});
  }
}
```